# Set background band to detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to set a background to my detail band in order to set vertical lines  (column separator), like in this picture :

[image]

How can I define the background band only for the detail band?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have several bands at report? Do you want to apply background only for **one** band (Detail), not for all?

Comment: `I would like to set a background to my detail band in order to set vertical lines (column separator), like in this picture` - It is a bad idea to use Background band just for drawing borders at table.

Comment: A background band for table borders is necessary for complex layouts where the table borders must be of a given height on a single page so that the page has a fixed layout. However, @AlexK is correct in that this is probably not one of those times. Consider using a table that grows dynamically, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "print when expression" of background band. Set the expression in such a way that it would check the presence/value of any mandatory of the components in detail band. In such a way you can ensure that the background band doesn't gets printed when detail band is empty.

Comment: How is this solving the task? The original question was: `How can I define the background band only for the detail band?`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need the background band to be printed only when detail band gets printed. Is that right ?

Comment: I'm not an author of a question :)

Comment: If that is the case, whichever band is going to be printed mandatorily, can be used for ensuring the print of background band.

Comment: My report is an invoice, so I will always have data to be printed in the report. I just want to print it nicely with borders and a fixed height as it is done in the sample. The background may do the thing even if I don't think it's a very nice solution. But if it's the only one, I ll go for it!

Comment: I just have : header, column header, detail, summary bands.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?